# emulating a variable size struct in C; allignment, performance issues

Tags: c, memory-management, struct, memory-alignment

It is possible to put arrays with custom length anywhere in a struct in C, but in that case additional `malloc` calls are required. Some compilers allow having VLAs anywhere in a struct, but that is not standard compliant. So I decided to emulate VLAs within struct for standard C.

I am in a situation where I really do have to get the maximum performance. The code in C will be automatically generated, so readability or style is not important in this case.

There will be structs with many custom size array members in between static size members. Below is a very simple form of such structs.

```
struct old_a {
    int n_refs;
    void **refs;
    int count;
};

struct old_a *old_a_new(int n_refs, int count) {
    struct old_a *p_a = malloc(sizeof(struct old_a));
    p_a->n_refs = n_refs;
    p_a->refs = malloc(n_refs * sizeof(void *));
    p_a->count = count;
    return p_a;
}

#define old_a_delete(p_a) do {\
    free(p_a->refs);\
    free(p_a);\
} while (0)
```

The additional `malloc` call for `refs` can be avoided as follows.

```
#define a_get_n_refs(p_a) *(int *)p_a
#define a_set_n_refs(p_a, rval) *(int *)p_a = rval
#define a_get_count(p_a) *(int *)((char *)p_a + sizeof(int) + a_get_n_refs(p_a) * sizeof(void *))
#define a_set_count(p_a, rval) *(int *)((char *)p_a + sizeof(int) + a_get_n_refs(p_a) * sizeof(void *)) = rval
#define a_get_refs(p_a, i) *(void **)((char *)p_a + sizeof(int) + i * sizeof(void *))
#define a_set_refs(p_a, i, rval) *(void **)((char *)p_a + sizeof(int) + i * sizeof(void *)) = rval

static void *a_new(int n_refs, int count) {
    void *p_a = malloc(sizeof(int) + n_refs * sizeof(void *) + sizeof(int));
    a_set_n_refs(p_a, n_refs);
    a_set_count(p_a, count);
    return p_a;
}

#define a_delete(p_a) do {\
    free(p_a);\
} while (0)
```

The emulated version seems to run 12~14% faster in my machine than the one with a pointer array. I assume it is due to the halved number of calls to `malloc` and `free`, and the reduced number of dereferencing. The test code is below.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    const int n_as = atoi(argv[1]) * 10000;
    const int n_refs = n_as;
    const int count = 1;
    unsigned int old_sum = 0;
    unsigned int sum = 0;
    clock_t timer;

    timer = clock();
    struct old_a **old_as = malloc(n_as * sizeof(struct old_a));
    for (int i = 0; i < n_as; ++i) {
        old_as[i] = old_a_new(n_refs, count);
        for (int j = 0; j < n_refs; ++j) {
            old_as[i]->refs[j] = (void *)j;
            old_sum += (int)old_as[i]->refs[j];
        }
        old_sum += old_as[i]->n_refs + old_as[i]->count;
        old_a_delete(old_as[i]);
    }
    free(old_as);
    timer = clock() - timer;
    printf("old_sum = %u; elapsed time = %.3f\n", old_sum, (double)timer / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    timer = clock();
    void **as = malloc(n_as * sizeof(void *));
    for (int i = 0; i < n_as; ++i) {
        as[i] = a_new(n_refs, count);
        for (int j = 0; j < n_refs; ++j) {
            a_set_refs(as[i], j, (void *)j);
            sum += (int)a_get_refs(as[i], j);
        }
        sum += a_get_n_refs(as[i]) + a_get_count(as[i]);
        a_delete(as[i]);
    }
    free(as);
    timer = clock() - timer;
    printf("sum = %u; elapsed time = %.2f\n", sum, (double)timer / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled with `gcc test.c -otest -std=c99`:

```
>test 4
old_sum = 3293684800; elapsed time = 7.04
sum = 3293684800; elapsed time = 6.07

>test 5
old_sum = 885958608; elapsed time = 10.74
sum = 885958608; elapsed time = 9.44
```

Please let me know if my code has any undefined behaviors, implementation defined behaviors et cetera. It is meant to be 100% portable for machines with a sane (standard compliant) C compiler.

I am aware of memory alignment issues. The member of these emulated structs will only be `int`, `double`, and `void *`, so I think there will not be alignment problems, but I am not sure. Also although the emulated struct appreared to run faster in my machine (Windows 7 64bit, MinGW/gcc), I do not know how it is likely to run with other hardware or compilers. Other than checking about standard guarenteed behavior, I really need help about hardware knowledge; which one is more machine friendly code (preferably in general)?

Comment: `(void *)j` seems strange to me... Why not use a `union` to tidy it up? This all smells like premature optimisation, particularly the part where you're timing this as a program by itself. If you focus on anything but the significant bottlenecks, you may be pushing your most significant optimisations out of sight. 1. Focus on writing clear, maintainable code which solves your *actual problem*. 2. Run your code using a profiler to determine what the most significant bottlenecks are. 3. Optimise those bottlenecks. 4. Run the profiler again to verify the optimisations, and repeat from 3. ...

Comment: Your example code does not contain a variable-length `struct`.  It contains a fixed-length struct, one of whose members is a pointer.  This is utterly standard conforming.  No C compiler will object to the `struct` definition.  In particular, note that whatever, if anything, is pointed to by the pointer member of an instance of such a `struct` is not itself part of the `struct`.

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour `(void *)j` is just for test case. I put that to test assignment and accessing. 12% performance increase is significant enough in my situation. I believe when applying this to structs with more arrays, the performance increase will be greater due to even more less `malloc` and `free` calls.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I know what is happening. The point is on saving additional `malloc` and `free` calls for faster code.

Comment: In x86 systems if your array data and the struct fit in the CPU cache it's much faster than if it doesn't. General info here:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Unless a sizable proportion of the work of your program is going to be allocating and freeing these data structures, the difference you observed in allocation / deallocation speed is unlikely to make a significant difference in the program's overall execution time.

Furthermore, do be aware that the two approaches are not equivalent.  The latter does not produce a representation of a `struct old_a`, so any other code that uses the data structure produced must use the provided access macros (or an equivalent) to do so.

Moreover, the roll-your-own-struct approach has potential alignment issues.  Depending on the implementation-dependent sizes and alignment requirements for various types, it may cause the members of the pointer array inside the pseudo-struct to be misaligned.  If it does, then either a speed penalty or possibly even a program crash will result.

More generally, there are few safe assumptions about sizes of type representations.  It is certainly **un**safe to assume that the size of an `int` is the same as the size of a `void *`, or that either one is the same size as a `double`.

Comment: So do you mean that even if `int`, `double`, or `void *` can only be a member of this packed pseudo-struct, there can be alignment problems?

Comment: @xiver77, with your example code, the `void *`s in the middle of the structure may be misaligned.  For instance, if pointers are 64 bits wide and want 64-bit alignment, but `int`s are 32-bits wide, then your example code *will* misalign *all* the pointers.

Comment: `the speed difference you tested is unlikely to be significant.` Nonsense. Memory access pattern would be very different. Having linear structure (all allocated in one go) is a lot better due to existence of such thing as prefetcher. I bet 12-14% difference @xiver77 sees is due to better memory access, not multiple allocations

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux, all he tested was the speed of allocating and freeing his data structures.  It is *that* difference that I said is unlikely to be significant.  Moreover, although it is certainly true that better locality of reference contributes to better performance, the ordinary `struct` approach could yield equivalent locality of reference in many common cases, given the memory allocation pattern presented.

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux, I have updated my answer to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

one thing to note - on some systems, int will be 2 bytes instead of 4. In that case, int will only reach 32767. Since you multiply the input by 10000, it will almost definitely cause problems on such machines. Use long instead.

Comment: Although this is true, it's more a commentary on the test program, not on the main code of interest.

Answer (score -1):

> It is possible to put arrays with custom length anywhere in a struct in C, but in that case additional malloc calls are required

No it isn't

There is famous "struct hack" to get structure with array allocated in one go

```
struct name {
    int namelen;
    char namestr[1];
};
```

And then

```
struct name *makename(char *newname)
{
    struct name *ret = malloc(sizeof(struct name)-1 + strlen(newname)+1);
            /* -1 for initial [1]; +1 for \0 */
    if(ret != NULL) {
        ret->namelen = strlen(newname);
        strcpy(ret->namestr, newname);
    }

    return ret;
}
```

See http://c-faq.com/struct/structhack.html for details

UPDATE

As mentioned, array to be last member of the struct, that might be unreasonable restriction

UPDATE

IN C99 this is now blessed way, called `flexible array member`, declaration shall be modified to be

```
struct name {
    int namelen;
    char namestr[];
};
```

and then it will work and allocated in one go

Comment: And C99 has variable-length members in the standard, so that this hack is not needed.  The OP's key assertion though, is that some compilers permit variable-length members may be placed *anywhere* in a struct (as opposed to only as the last member).  To the best of my knowledge he's wrong about that, but this answer is anyway not responsive.

Comment: @JohnBollinger In C99 it not a hack anymore, see update

Comment: Yes, I explicitly pointed out C99 VLAs in my comment.  They are a standardized way to approach the problem that the struct hack was used for.  The two are not the same, and the struct hack is still a hack.  In any case, none of that makes this answer any more responsive to the actual question, which is primarily about (pseudo-)VLAs in the middle of a struct, rather than at the end.

Comment: @JohnBollinger No, that is not correct. They are completely different things. In C99 flexible array member is §6.7.2.1-16 and are related to structure/union definition. And  hack is not a hack anymore, code like I posted  now could be found in this chapter. VLAs are defined at  §6.7.5 and down and related to array definition.

Comment: Ok, you're right that I was getting my terminology mixed up.  However, you are still mistaken about the struct hack.  The code you posted does not define a variable length array in C99, because per C99/6.7.5.2/4, "If the size [given in the array declaration] is an integer constant expression [...], the array type is not a variable length array."  It is a fixed-length array of the specified size, and accessing elements beyond its declared bounds (as the struct hack involves) results in undefined behavior.  Relying on undefined behavior is what makes the struct hack a hack.